# If the sum of digits of $n$ (where $n \geq 10$ and is not divisible by $2$ or $5$) is equal to $1$, $2$, $4$, $5$, $7$ or $8$, then $n$ is a prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I was fascinated by prime numbers and was trying to understand them.
I came up with the statement below which seems to be true for all prime numbers.

> If the sum of digits of $n$ (where $n \geq 10$ and is not divisible by $2$ or $5$) is equal to $1$, $2$, $4$, $5$, $7$ or $8$, then $n$ is a prime.

I am not taking into account primes with a single digit here.

Can this be formulated in any form in mathematics?

Comment: It's just false.  $121$ for example has digit sum $4$ but it is not prime.  As an exercise, you should try to construct a counterexample for each of your possible digit sums.

Comment: May be worth remarking that no sensible variant of this claim can be true.  The digit sum function is periodic $\pmod 9$ and there are arbitrarily long consecutive strings of composite numbers.

Comment: $1001$ is a counterexample for digit sum $2$. In fact, almost every number of the form $10^n+1$ is a counterexample for digit sum $2$.

Comment: The implication goes the other way: If it's a prime, then the sum of digits (or sum of digits of sum of digits, or sum of digits of sum of digits of sum of digits, etc) is equal to one of $1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8$.  The converse is not true: For example, the digits of $22$ sum to $4$, but $22$ is not prime. ¶ This successive sum of digits is called a **digital root**, and gives the value of the original number modulo $9$ (except that numbers divisible by $9$ have digital root $9$).  So any number divisible by $3$ will have digital root $3$, $6$, or $9$, and therefore cannot be prime.

Comment: The obligatory Wikipedia plot summary for [digital root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root).  P.S.  Obviously $3$ is prime.  It is the only number with digital root $3$, $6$, or $9$ that can be prime.

Comment: And with digit sum $1$ , there is no prime number at all.

Comment: thanks All for your comments and correcting...I was just playing with numbers and found some combination and your explanation holds true.

Comment: Not true as $10, 20, 12, 22, 14, 52, 35$ are not prime.
If you means the other way:  If $n$ is prime then the sum of digits is $1,2,4,5,7,8$. Then that isn't true as some primes have sums that are more than $10$. 
If you mean that: If $n$ is prime then successive summing of the digits to an ultimate single digit, will result in either $1,2,4,5,7$ or $8$--- then that *is* true.
And that is because if a number results in $3,6$ or $9$ then it is a multiple of $3$ and can not be prime (if $n > 3$).  SO if it is prime then $1,2,4,5,7$ or $8$ are the only remaining options ($0$ is impossible)

Comment: @fleablood Was the specification that $n$ is not divisible by either $2$ or $5$ made *after* your comment?